# Running Parallel Tasks

Tags: build, scripting, parallel-processing, automation, gradle

There is any way to run dependsOn tasks in parallel?

I have many tasks on dependsOn:

```
task compileTTS32(dependsOn: [compileTTS32Debug, compileTTS32Release])
task compileTTS64(dependsOn: [compileTTS64Debug, compileTTS64Release])

task compileTTS(dependsOn: [compileTTS32, compileTTS64])
```

Is there any way to run all `compile` tasks in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that at present, however if you were able to make TTS32 and TTS64 seperate sub-projects you should be able to get some level of parralellism with [http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:parallel_execution](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec%3aparallel_execution)